# SQl file handling class or library in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I don't know if this is a valid question to ask here, but I am looking for a class of library available in c# asp.net that could handle and retrieve information and manipulate .sql file. I need it for a college project as I am creating auto admin panel generator for asp.net

Comment: What do you mean manipulate a .sql file? Are you looking to connect to a SQL server database? In any case, in .Net the System.Data and System.Data.SQLClient namespaces are a good place to start.

Comment: no not that. I need class that could retrieve information from user given .sql or .db file about the database i.e. tables, constraints, relations, columns etc @RyanWilson